# How to use PHP with Composition API VueJS 3

Tags: php, vue.js

Coming from a PHP/jQuery background, where you can have PHP and jQuery code in the same file, for example some file called `index.php`:

```
<?php
echo "hey";
?>

<script>
$("#someId").html("abc")
</script>
```

How can you do something similar with the Composition API in **VueJS v3** where you can access access your PHP variables/sessions etc. inside of a `.vue` file or have your SFC files to include PHP code as well?

I know you can do this by including the vue framework with script tags inside of your index.php file but as far as I'm aware you can't use the Composition API with this method.

I'm probably missing something basic but I haven't been able to find the answer.

Comment: "as far as I'm aware you can't use the Composition API with this method and instead have to use Options API" - but you didn't specify the code with options api. It would be more relevant than a snippet with jQuery

Comment: PHP has absolutely nothing to do with Vue.JS - the former is executed on the server while the latter is executed in the browser. You can use either Options API, or Compositions API, or mix them both in any combination - and PHP will still happily run on the server.

Comment: I want to combine PHP for a login/db connection etc. but I don't see how I can combine the PHP code within the same file as the Vue code. I know I can use axios for API requests however I want to be able to access php session data directly within the same file.